# indexing confusion Stack LIFO

Tags: java, indexing, stack, lifo

I've been teaching myself Java with http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr15/cos126/lectures.html as a reference.  I was just going over the topic of `Stack` and they had the following code as an example

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdIn;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdOut;

public class StrawStack
{
    private String[] a;
    private int N=0;

    public StrawStack(int max)
    { a = new String[max];}

    public boolean isEmpty()
    { return (N==0);}

    //push a string on top of the stack
    public void push(String item)
    { a[N++] = item;}

    //return the last string added to the top of the stack 
    // this is what gets printed out in the main method
    public String pop()
    { return a[--N];  }

    public int size()
    { return N;} 

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
     int max = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
     StrawStack stack = new StrawStack(max);
     while (!StdIn.isEmpty())
     {
      String item = StdIn.readString();
      if (item.equals("-"))
      { StdOut.print(stack.pop() + " ");}
      else
      { stack.push(item);}
     }
    }
    //StdOut.println();   
}
```

The use `to be or not to – be - - that - - - is` as an input and then the output is `to be not that or be`, which makes sense because `-` makes the code print out the last string.  My confusion is how this ends up working out when it has `a[--N]` in the `pop` method.  I wrote out the `to be or not to –` part of the input on paper and kept track of indices.  I thought it goes like so:

`(a[0] stays default`  `a[1] = to` `a[2]= be`  `a[3]= or`  `a[4]=not` `a[5]=to`until it runs into `-`, then it calls upon `pop`.  My confusion is, somehow the code calls upon pop and returns `a[5] = to` instead of `a[4] = not`, which i think should be the case.  Because right before it runs into `-`, `N = 5` and then after hitting `-`, `N` gets assigned `4` if im not mistaken (which i must be)

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the question is not about a++ and ++a, but about how the indices are used by the Stack...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code, N is the index of the next empty space, not the index of the last inserted String in the stack. So when doing a[--N], this indeed decreases N first, but it points then to the last inserted item, "to".

When encountering the first "-", the stack is as follows:

```
a[0] = "to"
a[1] = "be"
a[2] = "or"
a[3] = "not"
a[4] = "to"
```

and N is 5.

Comment: thank you! this makes perfect sense. for some reason i thought --N is the same as N--